# I am not able to hide statusBar when I try to show a view

Tags: swift, ios-statusbar

I want to hide `statusBar` when I show a `view` in screen.

```
func showView() {

    if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow{
        let view = UIView(frame: keyWindow.frame)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        keyWindow.addSubview(view)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            view.frame = keyWindow.frame
        }) { (completedAnimnation) in
            //hide status bar when view is showed
            UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
        }
    }

}
```

---

This is the code that I show the view and I try to hide statusBar using :  `UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true` . and also `UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarHidden(true, with: .fade)` but none of these are working. Also can not `override prefersStatusBarHidden` because I am on a `UIView` class.

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Note: Please, do not mark as duplicate because I have seen all other
 answers but none of them are working.I don't want to hide for all application, only when It shows the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**step 1:**  In Info.plist file
       Click the plus button to add new key `View controller-based status bar appearance`
       Set the VALUE to `NO`

**step 2:**  For hide in a single screen

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
}
```

**step 3:** For hide in entire app
`AppDelegate.swift`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject:AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    application.statusBarHidden = true
    return true
}
```

Comment: I don't want to hide for entire app, only when I show that view.

Comment: you can use "UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true/false" as per your wish(on button click or etc.)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a variable:

```
var isVisible: Bool?
```

Set it to true when your desired UIView appears, and false when it disappears.

Alternatively, just use a ViewController, and present the view from there -

Comment: please, if you read my question I specified that, I am on an UIView class, can not override it

Comment: what is keeping you from using a VC and calling that view from that vc?