# How to hide Status bar programatically(swift) in a specific view controller?

Tags: swift, statusbar

Show/Hide Status bar using key-value of `UIApplication.shared`.
I have tried Overriding method `prefersStatusBarHidden` but it didn't get the result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52037589/8294374

Comment: @EneaDume it is deprecated

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44066303/6059313

Comment: Check this out, this guy had the same issue as you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35028262/how-to-hide-status-bar-of-a-single-view-controller-in-ios-9

Answer (score 0):

View controller without status bar

```
class ViewControllerWithoutStatusBar: UIViewController {

     //your logic here

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

View controller with status bar

```
class ViewControllerWithStatusBar: UIViewController {

     //your here here

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```